# Changing graphics item in a canvas

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracleforms

I use Form 6 . I would like to change the label that is on a canvas using program code. It appears as graphics item. (Graphics type:text)
Is it possible?

At the moment, my answer is that not possible.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct, a graphics text element (we call it boilerplate text) cannot be modified at runtime.

To modify the appearance of boilerplate in a Form, you can create a text item in a control block, set its value to the label you want to show, and change its display properties so it looks how you want (e.g. no bevel, transparent, etc.). Then you can change it at runtime to whatever label you want.

Just be careful, if the user (or your code) runs a `CLEAR_FORM` (or, indeed, a `CLEAR_BLOCK` on your control block), the label will disappear: so you need to set the `Initial Value` as well.